# Install Ubuntu on my computer via Network Boot

Tags: networking, system-installation

My Computer Hard disk is erased. So, no OS is available in the disk. Do not have USB options to Install Bootable Ubuntu. The only option is to install from Network Boot from the Bios Option.

So, How can I install Ubuntu via the Network Boot option?

Comment: Why is USB not an option? Is this a super old computer that won't boot off USB?

Comment: USB is not working and I cannot make it work as I got locked down due to COVID 19

Answer (score 0):

Network boot requires another computer to serve up the ISO image(s). There is a `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/PXE-netboot-install` but it's pretty complex. Might be easier to take the hard disk out, place it in another computer and do the install there.